# Как сделать переход с заданным title

Tags: javascript, html

На странице нужна форма ввода текста и кнопка "Перейти".
После ввода текста в форму и нажатия кнопки должна открыться страница с title заданным форме. Нужно именно так, чтобы открывалась новая страница, а не просто менялся title.

Answer (score 1):

Передавай отдельно в GET нужный `title` и на второй странице его считывай.

Функция на JS, которая возвращает нужный GET-параметр:

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    location.search
        .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
          tmp = item.split("=");
          if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        });
    return result;
}
```

Допустим, ты передаёшь так: `index.html?new_title=newpage`. И тогда

```
var new_page_title = findGetParameter('new_title');
document.title = new_page_title;
```

Всё. Проверки добавить по вкусу.

---

Первый файл (где форма):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="proc.html" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="new_title" />
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Второй файл (где меняется заголовок):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Первоначальный заголовок (ты его не должен увидеть)</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
                var result = null,
                    tmp = [];
                location.search
                    .substr(1)
                    .split("&")
                    .forEach(function (item) {
                      tmp = item.split("=");
                      if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
                    });
                return result;
            }

            var new_page_title = findGetParameter('new_title');
            document.title = new_page_title;
        </script>
        вторая страница с изменяемым заголовком
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы можете дать два готовых файла первый с полем для ввода и кнопкой перейти второй который будет открываться с заданным title или ссылку на пример

Comment: и ключ от квартиры, где деньги лежат

Comment: При чем тут ключ я и спрашивал потому что понятия не имею как сделать думал поможете

Comment: я помог. я тебе дал готовое решение. и если у тебя есть хотя бы базовое понимание того, как работает HTML и как работает веб-форма, моего ответа вполне достаточно. если же такого понимания нет, то следующим вопросом будет "А что теперь с этими файлами делать?"

Comment: с готовыми файлами я точно разберусь если не трудно дайте их

Comment: @ЗарядисьПозитивом обновил ответ. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо все работает

Comment: Спасибо то что вы дали работает дело в том что на открывшейся странице я планировал установить скрипт видео плеера который считывает title и находит фильм но скрипт считывает первоначальный заголовок а не тот который подставляется можете подсказать как так сделать чтобы скриптом плеера считывался подставляемый заголовок вот адрес страницы где я установил форму http://temadlyavseh.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: @ЗарядисьПозитивом легко. вставляй скрипт плеера ПОСЛЕ кода, который я прислал. по крайней мере, код, который инициализирует плеер. И да, если решенее работает, тыкни галочку :)

Comment: Я так и сделал вставил скрипт плеера <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hdgo.cc/content/base/video_api.php?token=i1jtpo159llclviwwcg0tyef&w=600&h=360"></script>
<div id="hdgoplayer"></div> вместо  слов вторая страница с изменяемым заголовком на странице proc.html но плеер все равно считывает <title>Первоначальный заголовок (ты его не должен увидеть)</title>

Comment: Жаль что ни кто не может предложить решение